Controller Variable Value Not Showing in Thymeleaf Fragment
So I have a Spring Boot Project that uses Java, JavaScript, and Thymeleaf and what I'm trying to do is take a String value and show it on a navigation bar fragment that I insert into various pages. Through Sys.out I am able to confirm the variable 'loggedInUsername' is carrying the correct value. Everywhere I have read says this should be right but my navigation bar never shows a value...
Here is my LoginController.java
package com.msu.ctap.Controllers;

import com.msu.ctap.Service.LoginService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    private final LoginService loginService;

    @Autowired
    public LoginController(LoginService loginService) {
        this.loginService = loginService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String loginPage() {
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/loginUser")
    public ModelAndView loginUser(@RequestParam("usernameOrEmail") String usernameOrEmail, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
        boolean loginSuccessful;

        loginSuccessful = loginService.loginUser(usernameOrEmail, password);

        String loggedInUsername = loginService.emailUsername(usernameOrEmail);

        ModelAndView modelAndView;
        if (loginSuccessful) {
            modelAndView = new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/upload"));
            System.out.println(loggedInUsername); //<--- Shows correct value
            modelAndView.addObject("loggedInUsername", loggedInUsername);
        } else {
            modelAndView = new ModelAndView("login");
            modelAndView.addObject("error", "Login failed. Please check your username/email and password.");
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }

}

Here is my Thymeleaf fragment navbar.html:
<div th:fragment="navbar">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a th:href="@{/about}">Devs</a></li>
            <li><a th:href="@{/upload}">Upload</a></li>
            <li><a th:href="@{/home}"><span class="nav-title">CTAP</span></a></li>
            <li><a th:href="@{/images}"}>Images</a></li>
            <li><a th:href="@{/help}">Help</a></li>
            <li>Welcome, <!--/*@thymesVar id="variableName" type="java.lang.String"*/-->
            <span th:text="${variableName}">!</span></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="hamburger-menu-icon">☰</div>
    </nav>
</div>

Here is my output:
Output
Here is my project structure:
Structure
I tried ModelAndView.addObject() and I tried using the Thymeleaf variable insert on the upload page outside of the navigation bar. I feel like the Controller is just unable to communicate with the HTML fragment
